# How to pass string parameters to C++ function using ctypes, python

Tags: python, c++, dll, ctypes

I have a C++ DLL library. One function is shown as below.

The DLL import in Python is correct.

```
int _ParseLogin2Resp(const std::string& username,
                     const std::string& password,
                     char szErr[1024]);
```

In fact, I have tried many ways to pass parameters. I know the difference between C++ `std::string` and `char *`.

1.Use the c_char_p() and byref()

```
username = ctypes.c_char_p("username")
_ParseLogin2Resp(ctypes.byref(username),...)
```

2.Use create_string_buffer()

```
username = ctypes.create_string_buffer("username")
_ParseLogin2Resp(username,...)
```

But function ERROR returns

> The username or password is empty.

So I couldn't find any solution to pass string parameters to my function.

My Question is.

Is it possibility that I could pass correct parameters to call my function as expected or I have to rewrite my dll library to make function work correctly?

Comment: Write a c function that accept char*, and in this function invoke the cpp function you needed.

Answer (score 0):

Python doc says ctypes provides C compatible data types, it is better to use c style API interface in your DLL.